# Can a Windows virus access virtual disks with another system?

Tags: linux, windows, virus, virtual-disk

I am using 2 operation system via Grub, Linux for work and Windows for games.

My question is, if I get some virus on Windows, can it some how damage my files that are stored on a disk with Linux? Or get access for files on Linux disk? Can a virtual disk be exposed to some another vulnerabilities from another virtual disk with infected Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can. The virus can and will do what it is supposed to do. "Virus" is a very broad term for this question. Can you give a little more details or context?

Comment: I'm more interested in the question of whether any malware installed on Windows, for example, along with another program, can access files on a Linux disk, and steal logins and passwords from Linux disk.

Comment: It can if those aren't encrypted. It depends of the type of the threat.